# How do I include the last instance of the condition met for the if statement?

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, if-statement

I have a document that I am reading and writing to. Information is listed with a timestamp at the beginning of every entry. I am trying to populate the dateNTimeArr array with datetime objects for every entry but I notice that the last entry is not appending to the array, no matter how many entries I have. I'm not sure how to solve this.

#### this an example of the text file I am reading and writing to.

In this example, the array will populate with the datetime objects I create from the first and second entry but it doesn't append the last one. 

 2021-08-10 16:26:12 
123 
123 
123 
123 
123 
2021-08-10 16:26:28 
123 
123 
123 
123 
123 
2021-08-10 16:27:15 
123 
123 
123 
123 
123

I tried removing the '\n' from the start of the while loop which seemed to work but the next time I ran the code, it messed with the format and kind of broke. Sorry in advance for the lack of structure to my code.

```
f = open("filename", "r")    
dateNTimeArr = []
    
for line in f:
    if "2021" in line:
        datentime = line.split(" ")
        datePart = datentime[0]
        timePart = datentime[1]
        hours, mins, secs = timePart.split(":")
        year, month, day = datePart.split("-")
        date1 = date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
        time1 = time(int(hours), int(mins), int(secs))
        datetime1 = datetime.combine(date1, time1)  
        dateNTimeArr.append(datetime1)
            
f.close()

f = open("filename", "a+")
    
    
submitBool = FALSE
while submitBool == FALSE:
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(now)
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(aQuantity.get())
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(bQuantity.get())
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(cQuantity.get())
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(dQuantity.get())
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(eQuantity.get())
    submitBool = TRUE

f.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop at the end? It will only run once because you set `submitBool` to `TRUE` unconditionally.

Comment: Also, it's `True` and `False`, not `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: I put `print(dateNTimeArr)` after the first loop, the list had 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

As Bramar mention, the list has 3 elements, you never printed it to check that.
Also, you have a few mistakes, in the `while loop`. The bool values are `True` and `False` not `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
And the loop will only run once because you changed it to `True` at the end of it.